# Remove subfolders in URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble with rewriting my URL. I want it to rewrite "domain.com/folder1/page1" to "domain.com/page1". My code is working properly but when I try to access folder2, it's automatically rewriting to "domain.com/folder1/folder2/page2". I want it to stay to "domain.com/folder2/page2". The only folder that I need to rewrite is for folder1. I have this current code right now. I don't know what to do

```
#for removing extension
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#Removing subfolders
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /folder1/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^apt/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule !^folder1/ folder1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Can you please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
```

This should remove `folder1` from all of your URLs. Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this.